# Extra space in table when using javascript width

Tags: javascript

Instead using CSS width for each table, I am using javascript to make tables automatically wide as the amount of text inside cells. But it also leaves white-space (green-space) at the most right side of table when scroll the horizontal scroll-bar. Which code is making this white-space and what is a good way to remove this white-space?

See Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKqwqR (my screen size: 1366*768)

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
  <table>
<tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>INFO----1</th>
    <th>INFO----2</th>      
    <th>Digits</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>What is google? - Computer Hope 
www.computerhope.com/jargon/g/google.htm
Originally known as BackRub, Google is a search engine that started development in 1996 by Sergey Brin and <br/>
Larry Page as a research project at Stanford University.
What is Google (the company)? - Definition from WhatIs.com 
</td>
    <td>What is google? - Computer Hope 
www.computerhope.com/jargon/g/google.htm
Originally known as BackRub, Google is a search engine that started development in 1996 by Sergey Brin and <br/>
Larry Page as a research project at Stanford University.
What is Google (the company)? - Definition from WhatIs.com 
</td>       
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>What is google? - Computer Hope 
www.computerhope.com/jargon/g/google.htm
Originally known as BackRub, Google is a search engine that started development in 1996 by Sergey Brin and <br/>
Larry Page as a research project at Stanford University.
What is Google (the company)? - Definition from WhatIs.com 
</td>
    <td>What is google? - Computer Hope 
www.computerhope.com/jargon/g/google.htm
Originally known as BackRub, Google is a search engine that started development in 1996 by Sergey Brin and <br/>
Larry Page as a research project at Stanford University.
What is Google (the company)? - Definition from WhatIs.com 
</td>       
    <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>What is google? - Computer Hope 
www.computerhope.com/jargon/g/google.htm
Originally known as BackRub, Google is a search engine that started development in 1996 by Sergey Brin and <br/>
Larry Page as a research project at Stanford University.
What is Google (the company)? - Definition from WhatIs.com 
</td>
    <td>What is google? - Computer Hope 
www.computerhope.com/jargon/g/google.htm
Originally known as BackRub, Google is a search engine that started development in 1996 by Sergey Brin and <br/>
Larry Page as a research project at Stanford University.
What is Google (the company)? - Definition from WhatIs.com 
</td>       
    <td>67</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table{ background:red; overflow-x:auto; }
table{ background:#aaffaa; border-collapse:collapse; display:block; }
th, td { border:1px solid #666; padding:10px; }
```

Javascript:

```
var i=0,row,table=document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],tabwid=table.offsetWidth;

while(row=table.rows[i++])
{var hei=row.offsetHeight;
 while(tabwid<4000)
 {tabwid+=500;table.style.width=tabwid+'px';
  if(row.offsetHeight==hei)
  {table.style.width=tabwid-500+'px';break;}
 }
}
```

EDIT: I found that visible table is  and extra white-space (green-space) is also a part of .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work with the following changes in your JS

I added a windowWidth variable so you get the width of every browser window.
Then instead of checking for 4000 as you previous had now you check the browser window size.

```
  var i=0,row,table=document.getElementsByTagName('table')

    var windowWidth =  window.innerWidth;   

    [0],tabwid=table.offsetWidth;

     while(row=table.rows[i++])
     {var hei=row.offsetHeight;
         while(tabwid<windowWidth)
           {tabwid+=500;table.style.width=tabwid+'px';
             if(row.offsetHeight==hei)
           {table.style.width=tabwid-500+'px';break;}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but when I use your script, there is no scroll bar and extra line breaks other than <br/> tags in cells, which is same as without javascript... any ideas?

Comment: i mean maximum table contents (text) will always be inside 40000 table width